# Recovering target folder files deleted from maven clean

Tags: maven

I added API request/response files in the target folder (following existing project structure) and didn't realize that running maven clean was going to delete them. Is there a way to recover files deleted in the target folder after a maven clean? I spent a long time working on them and don't want to have to remake everything. This was done in intellij for reference.

Comment: Check your IDE if there is a kind of history... Apart from that the `target` folder contains only generated/compiled stuff so never put something in there you need later... There is a local history in IDEA IntelliJ check that...also always commit first before doing something...

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you have some sort of disk backup running on your computer.